# Facebook Photo Contest App Against FB's TOS?

Tags: facebook, xfbml, storing-information

What would be possible/best practice for a Photo Contest app?

Saving photos to a database and refreshing the contents with an "infinite session"? Exporting photos to my site getting written consent from my user?

I've gathered that it won't be possible to present users with a number of photos to vote on because the permissions for user's photos will often not allow just anyone (the public) to view them.

I've looked at SnapIt! Photo Contest on Facebook and it appears they are successful with what I'm trying to do. Are they breaking the Facebook TOS?

http://apps.facebook.com/snapitphoto

I'm new to Facebook development and want to be sure it is possible to do what I want before I become very invested. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I found this in the FAQ of SnapIt!

"What do you do with my image when I submit a photo?


Your image is stored on our server so that we can display your contest entry to other participants without having to deal with Facebook album privacy issues."

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get a [facebook account representative](http://www.facebook.com/business/contact.php) to approve any competitions or sweepstakes. They may be able to guide you as to what you can and can't do.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a photo to SnapIt, then the photo is entirely under the control of SnapIt, and it shouldn't violate any of the Facebook rules that I am aware of.

But to be honest, you might want to check with a lawyer on that first, as I can't give true legal advice.

Comment: Is this suppose to be an answer?

Comment: I guess. Like ceejayoz said, this is a programming forum, not a legal advice one.